# Open a new JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a main JFrame that has all kinds of panels in it for different functions and people can calculate things in them. I want to open a new JFrame when the user hits the first calculate button and serve as a Output window (Simlar to SPSS output windows if you are familiar with them).

The New JFrame will be completely separate and will have its own menu bar ... A simple JDialog is not the way to go here.

Comment: So what's problem ? just make that `JFrame` visible when the first calculate button is clicked..!!!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655294/java-swing-multiple-windows][1]
Here is another thread that should answer your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655294/java-swing-multiple-windows

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- can't resist, simple disagree with answers `JFrame frame = new JFrame(`); and `frame.setVisible(true);`

> I want to open a new JFrame when the user hits the first calculate
>   button and serve as a Output window (Simlar to SPSS output windows if
>   you are familiar with them).

- [don't do that, create only two JFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime), reuse 2nd. `JFrame` by using `getContentPane.removeAll()`, for another actions from `JButton`
- then all lifecycle will be only about `setVisible(true)` / `setVisible(false)`
- change `DefaultCloseOperations` to `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`

> The New JFrame will be completely separate and will have its own menu
>   bar. A simple JDialog is not the way to go here.

- whats wrong with `JDialog`, only one button in the `Toolbar` in compare with three buttons in `JFrame`, simple disagree,

> Output window (Simlar to SPSS output windows if you are familiar with
>   them).

- use `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread` (required wrap into `invokeLater`) for get value for JComponents placed into JDialog, if all changes are done call `JDialog.setVisible(true)` wrapped into `invokeLater()`

Answer (score 11):

```
JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
newFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: please to wrap setVisible(true); into invokeLater

Comment: :-) this is to your answers

Comment: @SLaks In Java, the GUI-thread (EDT) is not the same as the main thread.

Comment: @mkorbel if the op isn't on the EDT, then both statements need to be placed with in InvokeLater ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer only pack(if exists) and setVisisble, welcome on SO :-)

Comment: Also it is bad practice to have more than one `JFrame` within the same  swing application, that's why we have `JDialog`.

Comment: @mkorbel there's no guarantee to when a UI component might try and interact with other parts of UI, always safer to create and manipulate on the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer slightly disagree (reason why we are here) the same [song as with our princessin see point f)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15137708/714968), I'm still sure that all value and used methods are static modifiers, then important is invoke pack(LayoutManager on EDT) and setVisible

Comment: How about the JInternalFrame.? Won't it be much user friendly and would fulfill what use is looking for.!!?

Comment: @mKorbel: He said he wants to do this in a button click handler.

Comment: @Vishal K (my view) by default multiple instances are required for multiple screens, this idea is correct, but not all methods are accessible betweens two or more JFrames as is decribed in API,

Comment: @SLaks correct, and the button-click handler is executed on the EDT, so your answer is correct +1. Though, I disagree of having multiple `JFrame`s.

Comment: @SLaks you are right, whatever invoked from Swing Listener is done on EDT,

Comment: @SLaks back to my invokeLater, described [SPSS](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/) by OP could be hard and long running Object, SwingWorker or invokeAndWait is proper of ways

Comment: @mKorbel I'm happy to admit that was more the 5 years ago I read the article and I may be taking it to literally, but my understand is, there is no guarantee when any window will attach itself to a native peer and is "safer" not to assume, especially between implementations, so rather the risking, I simply fall under the "create it all on the EDT" rule :) - ps I'm always happy for an argument - it helps me learn |)

Comment: @MadProgrammer :-) we wrote here about important rulles, but see world is really mad&crazy, everything is possible  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7442529/714968),  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14988796/714968) and  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9301453/714968), those examples aren't about following good practices.....

Comment: There is no problem when we use so many JFrame instead of JDialog.. The most important is user accept our program. That is the main goal of software development..

Answer (score 5):

Never use more than one [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) within a Swing application. Use [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) for extra windows instead.

See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/597657).

Comment: For (almost) every rule there is an exception - good to point it out though ;)

Answer (score 4):

I maybe mis understanding your question but

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: not the same issue, see comments to the answer by his majesty @SLaks

Comment: The question can lead people to mis understanding haha

Answer (score 0):

I used code `JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);`. This block of code just do empty window.